# CUANTOS CARACTERES IGUALES ELIMINO DE UNA LISTA -FUNCION

Tags: python

en una lista si se encuentran tres o mas caracteres iguales consecutivos se eliminan.  los caracteres restantes de la lista luego de de la eliminación se reagrupan y se vuelve a validar si quedan 3 o mas caracteres iguales para eliminarlos nuevamente.

La función debe retornar cuantos caracteres elimine.  Lo trato de hacer con two pointers pero hay casos que no me funcionan

Ej. entrada `[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]`
resultado 10 caracteres eliminados

encuentra primero 1,1,1 y elimina 3 elementos.
Al reagrupar queda. `[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]` eliminando 2,2,2 sumando 3 mas elementos eliminados.  Luego encuentra 3,3,3,3 y adiciona 4 elementos mas para un total de 10

Finaliza la función.  Gracias por cualquier sugerencia

```py
def lines(a):
    if len (a) < 3:
        nlines = 0
    else:       
        i, nballs = 0, 0
        j = i + 1  
        while j < len(a):
            if a[i] != a[j]:
                i += 1
                j += 1
            else:
                j += 1
                if a[i] == a[j]:
                    nlines = j - i + 1
                if i == 0:
                    i = j+1
                    j = i
                else:
                    a[j] = a[i-1]
                    a[i-1] = a[j-1]
                    i = j
                    j += 1
    return nballs
```

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y escribi correctamente tu programa. Ahora, cual es el problema?

Comment: gracias.. he tratado de usar two pointers pero tengo problemas cuando encuentro la secuencia de iguales muy al final de la lista.  He intentado con métodos menos eficientes con while cuando es igual y eliminar de la lista pero tampoco lo logro alguna sugerencia?

Comment: si.. primero edita la pregunta y mostra tu codigo correctamente...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te complicas mucho, lo bueno de las listas es que son mutables, es decir no se crea una nueva referencia al objeto al cambiar uno de sus valores.

Lo que se me ocurrió fue iterar en el rango de la lista e ir cogiendo numero de 3 en 3 es decir desde `i` hasta `i+3` y verificar si todo ese conjunto de elementos son iguales para lo cual se me ocurrió usar `set` que devuelve un conjunto de dato sin repeticiones por lo que si todos los elementos de `i` hasta `i+3` son iguales nos regresará un conjunto de un solo elemento, por lo que solo tendremos que verificar su longitud. Hasta  ahí todo bien, pero no siempre habrá 3 elementos seguidos sino más, por lo que tuve que guardar el ultimo elemento repetido encontrado para que así en la siguiente iteración comprobar si ese último elemento es igual al siguiente y si lo son pues eliminamos.

Para hacer todo esto me fue más conveniente usar un ciclo `while` ya que así puedo tener una variable de control que puedo modificar a gusto. Dado que al momento de eliminar elementos debemos de comenzar a  recorrer la lista desde 0 entonces solo modifico la variable de control (modificandola a 0 para empezar desde el inicio).

```py
def remove_consecutive(lista):
    if set(lista)==1: return len(lista)
    lista = lista.copy() #iteraremos en una copia de la lista
    #inicalizamos el contador y el ultimo elemento
    ultimo, i = None, 0 
    num_delete = 0 #contador de elementos eliminados
    while i in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[i]==ultimo: #si el elemento es igual al ultimo eliminado
            lista.pop(i)
            num_delete+=1
            continue
        else: ultimo=None #restablecemos su valor
        elements = lista[i:i+3] #obtenemos un conjunto de 3 elementos
        if len(elements)>2 and len(set(elements))==1: #verificamos que sean iguales
            ultimo = elements[0] #definimos el ultimo elemento
            del lista[i:i+3] #eliminamos los elementos
            num_delete+=3 
            i=0 #establecemos en 0 para iniciar desde el comienzo
            continue
        i+=1
    return num_delete
```

Al final retornamos la variable `num_delete` que tiene la contabilización de elementos eliminados y listo! Si tienes alguna duda puedes hacermela saber en los comentarios :D.

Comment: Muchas gracias.. ayuda un montón.. tengo un tema y es que puede haber un caso donde todos sean iguales y con grupos de a 3 quedo corto.. utilice otra variante usando del pero hay ejemplos que no funciona

Comment: por ejemplo para que casos?

Comment: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] el numero de eliminados es 5 y en el código nos vamos en grupos de 3 .. la condición es que elimina para mayores iguales. a 3

Comment: listo, arreglado :D